# How to show console commands output after it was hidden?

Tags: phpstorm

In phpstorm 2023 with double shift key I run some console commands which I tune in the IDE.
If this console is closed how a) can I reopen it ? b)view history of output of last commands without running commands ?

**A bit Details** :
Moreover I found that there are hot keys (Shift+Esc) to Close this console :

[image]

But I did not find how can I open this console without running  command again and existing output...

Comment: Generally, the answer would probably be "no" for both; however, could you please elaborate on what you mean by "which I tune in the IDE"? Is it External Tools, PHP Command Line tools, or something else?

Comment: Please read A bit Details

Comment: Ah, okay, it's clearer now. When you hide it, you can still access it by clicking the Run tool window button in the left IDE button strip (you have the strip half-trimmed on your screenshot). If you want to save the results between runs, you can pin the Run tool window tab via the right-click menu on the tab